# Perché i segnaposto da scrivania si chiamano cavalieri?

Tags: word-meaning, etymology

Ho sentito diverse volte chiamare i segnaposto da scrivania "cavalieri". Ho consultato alcuni vocabolari, ma non ho mai trovato la definizione di questo significato.

Cercando su Google "[Cavalieri da scrivania](https://www.google.it/?q=cavaliere%20da%20scrivania)" escono diversi risultati, quindi è evidentemente un modo di dire di uso comune.

Qualcuno conosce il motivo e/o l'origine per i quali i segnaposto da scrivania vengono chiamati cavalieri?

Comment: Personalmente – ma non vuol dire molto – non l'ho mai sentito. Per quanto riguarda Google, se metto le virgolette (e quindi escludo pagine in cui siano menzionati separatamente cavalieri e scrivanie) ne trovo tre di numero col singolare e due col plurale...

Comment: Non è la stessa cosa, ma la seconda accezione di [cavalierino](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/cavalierino/) secondo il Treccani sembra collegata. Forse l'idea è che i segnaposto siano cartoncini piegati in due, così da avere una forma che ricorda quella di un omino a cavallo molto stilizzato?

Comment: Ricordo di aver letto che il cavaliere era anche il nome di un supporto su cui una vedetta poteva salire per vedere più in lontananza, dovrei scovare il libro, forse l'uso di cavaliere per un supporto tipo leggio viene da quello per somiglianza di forma magari e poi è caduto anche sui segnaposto?

Comment: @DaG: Cercando segnaposto scrivania cavalieri su Google, si trovano alcuni cataloghi in cui i segnaposti da scrivania sono anche chiamati cavalieri.

Comment: Non l'ho mai sentito neanch'io. Forse è una forma caduta in disuso, o magari regionale?

Comment: @DaG ho aggiunto "da scrivania" perché altrimenti non sarebbero usciti i risultati che cercavo. Per quanto riguarda "cavalierino" potrebbe essere, forse è la forma ad U rovesciata a suggerire il nome.

Comment: @WalterVilla quello che dicevo è solo che se nella ricerca di Google inserisco <"Cavalieri da scrivania">, virgolette comprese, anziché semplicemente <Cavalieri da scrivania>, senza virgolette, ottengo un numero infimo di risultati.

Comment: @DaG, si avevo capito. Volevo solo specificare che "da scrivania" l'ho aggiunto io. Credo si chiamino semplicemente cavalieri.

Comment: Ah, bene, ho capito. Spero che qualcuno trovi la risposta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La parola non mi suona nuova. L'ho usata e sentita usare tante volte, partecipando a presentazioni di libri e convegni. Digitando cavaliere significato dizionario su Google, si possono leggere molti significati della parola "cavaliere". L'ultima definizione, quella che potrebbe esserci utile, è: «11. Cartoncino posto all'interno della custodia trasparente di una cassetta di registrazione, che reca l'intestazione e i titoli contenuti nella stessa».
Il cavaliere è quell'oggetto in plastica trasparente nel quale si può inserire un cartoncino o un foglio con il nome del relatore di un convegno o di una conferenza, in modo che chi vi assiste lo possa vedere. Direi che più che "da scrivania", i cavalieri sono oggetti per "tavoli da convegno o conferenza".

Comment: Secondo [questo blog](http://ilvocabolario.blogspot.com.es/2006/09/da-caudotomia-ceiba.html?m=1) questa definizione è del Devoto-Oli.

Comment: @Charo Grazie di averlo segnalato, non avevo trovato il riferimento.